# How to add a visual prefix to an entry in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Say I want to add a number prefix based on a country, for a phone entry? Like the one on the image: [image]
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <Label Text="+995 |" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
        <Editor Text="699999999" BackgroundColor="Transparent"></Editor>
 </StackLayout>
```

A Horizontal stacklayout with a label for the prefix and an editor for the entry.

As you can see yourself i am using the same approach for my app in order to display the arrow down icon next to the picker.

[image]

```
var datectrl = new NoBorderPicker()
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Default, typeof(Label)) * FontSizes.EditFormControlFactor,
                    HeightRequest = 40,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

                };

                var icon = new IconView()
                {
                    Source = "ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp",
                    Foreground = Palette._019,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0)
                };
                var stack = new StackLayout()
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Children =
                    {
                        datectrl,
                        icon
                    }
                };
```

The `NoBorderPicker` is a custom renderer in order to remove the border for the picker control

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoBorderPicker), typeof(CustomPicker))]
namespace ThesisSFA.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomPicker : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {

                var customBG = new GradientDrawable();
                customBG.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                customBG.SetCornerRadius(3);
                Control.SetBackground(customBG);

                var custdatepicker = (NoBorderPicker) this.Element;
                this.Control.TextSize = (float)custdatepicker.FontSize;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use masking behavior.

```
<Entry.Behaviors>
   <behavior:MaskedBehavior Mask="(995) XX-XXX-XXXX" />
</Entry.Behaviors>
```

enter code here
and to add behavior just use the following link.
https://xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/